# Emails being sent via Gmail API are getting BCC'd to the OAuth Connection email also

Tags: oauth, gmail, bcc

I have set up a Gmail OAuth App and OAuth Client Ids credentials.  This is done under the gmail account owned by someone who we will call greg@gmail.com.

When I send an email via that connection to any email (we will say bill@gmail.com), the email goes to bill@gmail.com but an exact copy is sent to greg@gmail.com as if he was BCC's on it.  Greg's copy has a send to of bill@gmail.com.

I have gone through this process twice trying to see if I messed up in my creation.  As I have done a couple of these before, I am confused as to what is going on with this one. Is the problem related to the fact that I created all the Gmail Oauth app and clientId's while logged in as greg instead of myself?

What/where do I look to see why emails being sent via greg's gmail API are apparently being BCC'd to him also? They should only go to the recipient.

I have created a 2nd Gmail Oauth App and Client Id and tested with that. The same problem exists. I was expecting only the recipient to get the email.

One test I run is using a google apps script which contains:
`GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);`

I then changed from using the Google API to using a an SMTP server (smtp.google.com) with the greg gmail username and an App password.  The same results are happening.